# force ssl for logged in users

Tags: mod-rewrite, ssl

I have a web application that we need to force SSL for, but only when the user is logged in. Unfortunately, the login page is the same url as the web application when a user is logged in.

I had the following rewrite for skipping SSL when the url was simply / or /signup but that fails because a) when a user is logged in, they may still be at / and not have any forced-ssl and b) when a user visits signup with an invite key, like signup?invite=123abc the pattern fails.

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/|signup)$
#RewriteRule (.*) https://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It feels like forcing SSL in apache is faster than from my PHP application but I'm not sure the best way to resolve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the language you are using server side it may be easier to do it in that rather than use a rewrite rule since your server side program would know that the user is logged in. Some pseudo code:

If user is logged in and request URL begins http then redirect to https.

Comment: Oh right, php. In that case the speed difference will be minimal unless you are on a very heavily trafficed site. Plus if after validating the login or after login itself you onlyoutput https urls then you will cut down on redirects anyway.

Comment: But I would assume the redirect would be much faster if done from Apache? I can go ahead and add it in the application code, no problem it just seems less efficient.

Comment: It may be a little faster but you would need to add extra bits for apache to validate that the user is logged in which would then slow you down.

Comment: Ok I'll just go that route then. Thanks